# MySQL self-join takes too long—can I streamline this query?

Tags: mysql, performance, self-join

I'm hoping (and pretty sure that) someone out there is much better at MySQL queries than msyelf.

I have a query which checks a table that contains information on :
- a search term
- title and price results from various sites using this search term

For the sake of streamlining, I've inserted the data already converted to lowercase with spaces removed and the whole thing trimmed to 11 characters to help reduce the load on the MySQL server.

The query is designed to find the maximum cost and minimum cost of likely equal titles and determine a price difference if it exists.

Having read some similar questions here, I've also prepended EXPLAIN EXTENDED to the query to see if that would help and I'm including the results along with the query.

The query as is :

```
SELECT
  a.pricesrch11,
  b.pricesrch11,
  a.pricegroup11,
  b.pricegroup11,
  a.priceamt - b.priceamt AS pricediff
FROM      ebssavings a
LEFT JOIN ebssavings b ON ( a.pricesrch11 = b.pricesrch11 ) 
                      AND (a.pricegroup11 = a.pricesrch11)
                      AND (b.pricegroup11 = a.pricesrch11)
WHERE a.priceamt - b.priceamt >0
GROUP BY a.pricesrch11
```

The results of the EXPLAIN :

```
    select_type | table | type | possible_keys            | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra
1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ALL  | pricesrch11,pricegroup11 | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 8816 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ALL  | pricesrch11,pricegroup11 | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 6612 | Using where
```

ADDENDUM :

I just ran this query and got the following result :

```
Showing rows 0 - 4 ( 5 total, Query took 66.8119 sec)


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ebssavings 
( priceid int(44) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
  priceamt decimal(10,2) NOT NULL, 
  pricesrch11 varchar(11) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
  pricegroup11 varchar(11) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
  pricedate timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  PRIMARY KEY (priceid), 
  KEY priceamt (priceamt), 
  KEY pricesrch11 (pricesrch11), 
  KEY pricegroup11 (pricegroup11) ) 
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8817
```

MORE INFO ON THE NEW INDEXES (removed pricegroup11, and made a composite index called srchandtitle from pricesrch11 and pricegroup11):

```
Edit     Drop   PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  priceid 169 A       
Edit     Drop   priceamt    BTREE   No  No  priceamt    56  A       
Edit     Drop   pricesrch11 BTREE   No  No  pricesrch11 12  A       
Edit     Drop   srchandtitle    BTREE   No  No  pricesrch11 12  A       
                                                pricegroup11 169    A
```

Comment: Please show the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.

Comment: What is the execution time if `GROUP BY a.pricesrch11` is omitted?

Comment: Random unhelpful tips: `(b.pricegroup11 = a.pricesrch11)` => `b.pricegroup11 = b.pricesrch11)`, `a.priceamt - b.priceamt >0` => `a.priceamt > b.priceamt`

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses.  I'm waiting for the create table now. I think the server is a little pissed at me.

Comment: I've added the CREATE TABE above.  And yes pricesrch11 and pricegroup11 and priceamt are indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the Key on pricegroup11 and add a composite clustered key on pricesrch11,pricegroup11.

Also move the table to InnoDB.

Comment: I've added the CREATE TABE above. And yes pricesrch11 and pricegroup11 and priceamt are indexed.

Comment: Individual Keys and Composite Keys are different.

Comment: I'm not sure how to make a composite key. I'm reading now but so far I  know that InnoDB automaking makes the primary key clustered. Still researching.

Comment: Oh, and I've made the table InnoDB as well. Still taking forever though.

Comment: Converting to InnoDB made it take 3 times longer!  Showing rows 0 - 4 ( 5 total, Query took 182.0334 sec)

Answer (score 2):

Create two indexes:

1. PriceSrch11
2. A clustered index on pricesrch11,pricegroup11

Comment: I have indexes on all the fields involved, but I'm not sure what a clustered index is.  I'll go find out.  Thank you.

Comment: @Aethon, based on your Create Table, you do not have a Composite Key on pricesrch11,pricegroup11. You need to delete the individual key on pricegroup11 and create a composite key on (pricesrch11,pricegroup11).

Comment: Would I remove both individual keys?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that things have sped up now with the changes made to the table and the indexes.

I've emptied the table and am beginning again.

Thank you all for your help.

-A